# How do I delay video from my webcam on my own feed?

Tags: video-capture

Id like to have the ability to delay the video from my webcam on. my own computer. Honestly I am using. it. as a "delayed mirror" for my golf swing. I have always recorded, then stopped, opened up the file and watched then did it again. Doing this 30 times in a session working on my swing is annoying. Id like to just take a webcam, be able to delay the video 5,8,10 seconds so I can watch and just keep moving. what is the easiest way around this. I have been told I could do this with a script but not sure where to start. Can anyone help me or send me in the right direction? Im on a Mac but also have a PC if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Python + OpenCV.

First manage to show a current image from your webcam using tutorials.

Then instead of immediately showing the image you add it at the end of a buffer object, this could be a [collections.deque](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#deque-objects) from standard Python.

If you want to delay for say 5 seconds and you're capturing with 30 frames per second, then don't show anything until you add 5*30 images from your camera to the buffer. Now when you filled the buffer as soon as you get another image, you add it to the end of the buffer, but also remove 1 image from the beginning of the buffer and show it.